# Format multiple affiliations/institutions for medRxiv

Tags: paper-submission, preprint

I am submitting to medRxiv. In the "author list" part of the submission process, each author has only one line for an institution. There are no obvious ways of adding more lines.

I can see that it is possible to have multiple institutions ([example](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2023.11.27.23297542v1))

I would try with a semicolon, but since there is no way of previewing the generated medRxiv page, and since it stays up forever, I am unwilling to try it out. What is the correct way of entering multiple institutions in the author information?

[image: MedRxiv author entry form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered in medRxiv's [faq](https://www.medrxiv.org/about/FAQ).

> **Why have some details changed in the Abstract or other metadata?** 
> Metadata details (manuscript title, author list, abstract, etc.) are
> supplied by the author during the submission process and initially
> post with the PDF. *These are replaced with final metadata extracted
> from each PDF file once the full text HTML is generated.* There may be
> small differences between the metadata the authors supply and the
> corresponding text derived from their PDF files.